# How to control iOS Safari from OS X

Tags: remote-desktop, automation, safari, remote-control, ios

While developing web apps I need to test results on multiple devices, and often need to change URLs to switch between prototypes, tests, and my main application.  Entering new addresses in a desktop browser is naturally quick and easy; however, updating the address on my devices is a slow and irritating.

I found LiveReload and use code snippets to automatically refresh current pages when I've edited code, but I'm wondering is there some sort of app or technique that allows remote control of iOS Safari or other mobile browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the iOS Simulator. It comes with the Xcode-app which you can [download from the App Store on Mac OSX](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/xcode/id497799835).

[image]

Then, you just have to start the iOS simulator. You can change between many different iDevices and test it in Mobile Safari.

Comment: Thanks.  iOS Simulator is great, I can copy and paste addresses from desktop to simulator, but it isn't automatic and I still need to see results on actual devices.  I imagine I'm wishing for something that doesn't exist yet, the ability to remotely control device browsers.